# Magento 1.9 - how to determine if customer already used discount code

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

How Magento know if the customer already used coupon code (unregistered customer).
Is Magento checking customer's IP or some other specific data?

Answer (score 2):

If your customer is not logged in (or has no account), Magento is not able to decide if he has or not used a coupon code.

Comment: So if customer already used the code on his computer and wasn't registered/loggedin but guest there is no way to avoid another purchase with the same code ?
What i would like to avoid is because I have a code w5 and customer used it once. Now he is using it again .... :( ... and will use again and again regardless if the code is configured to be user only once per person ...

Comment: the only way will be turn off the guest account right or demand registration first??

Comment: At the everyone-has-a-VPN era, IP checking is meaningless. You might have better luck with cookies. The simplest si to restrict your coupon to logged in users